# Same animation for 2 controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 labels, and I want to animate the `Margin` and `Opacity` property.

Both labels have the same animation, as you can see in the code below.

```
var marginAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation() { To = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 20) };
var opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation() { To = 1 };

var storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(marginAnimation);
storyboard.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);

//Doesn't work
Storyboard.SetTarget(marginAnimation, firstPlayerLabel);
Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnimation, firstPlayerLabel);

//Works
Storyboard.SetTarget(marginAnimation, secondPlayerLabel); 
Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnimation, secondPlayerLabel);

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(marginAnimation, new PropertyPath(MarginProperty));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));

storyboard.Begin();
```

But the animation only occurs in the last label. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Calling SetTarget a second time for an animation will obviously replace the target set in the first call. Use two Animations.

Comment: @Clemens I was looking for a way to do this without having to duplicate the animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a Storyboard:

```
firstPlayerLabel.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, marginAnimation);
secondPlayerLabel.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, marginAnimation);

firstPlayerLabel.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, opacityAnimation);
secondPlayerLabel.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, opacityAnimation);
```

Comment: Much better, It worked exactly as I wanted, thanks!